# Thread to process

Tags: c, multithreading, process

How can I rewrite this code to using process not thread? I try to learning process programming in C language. I don't have any idea how can I do this. This code uses thread. More info about this algoritmus is here on page 153 - 158 :

http://www.greenteapress.com/semaphores/downey08semaphores.pdf

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define MAX_PASSENGERS 500

sem_t loading, loaded, unloading, unloaded;

int n, c;

void *passenger (void *tid) {
  int i = *((int*) tid);

  while (1) {

    sem_wait(&loading);
    printf("pass(i=%d).board()\n", i);
    sem_post(&loaded);

    sem_wait(&unloading);
    printf("pass(i=%d).unboard()\n", i);
    sem_post(&unloaded);

  }
}

void *roller_coaster () {
  while (1) {

    printf("car.load(c=%d)\n", c);
    for (int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
      sem_post(&loading);
    }

    // wait for c passengers to load
    for (int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
      sem_wait(&loaded);
    }

    printf("car.run()\n");

    sleep(1);

    printf("car.unload(c=%d)\n", c);
    for (int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
      sem_post(&unloading);
    }

    // wait for c passengers to unload
    for (int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
      sem_wait(&unloaded);
    }

  }
}

int main () {

  printf("Number of passengers(n, n <= 500): ");
  scanf("%d", &n);
  printf("Number of passengers per cart(c, c < n): ");
  scanf("%d", &c);

  sem_init(&loading, 0, 0);
  sem_init(&unloading, 0, 0);

  sem_init(&loaded, 0, 0);
  sem_init(&unloaded, 0, 0);

  pthread_t car;
  pthread_t tid[MAX_PASSENGERS];

  int my_ids[MAX_PASSENGERS];

  pthread_create(&car, NULL, roller_coaster, NULL);

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    my_ids[i] = i;
    pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, passenger, &my_ids[i]);
  }

  pthread_join(car, NULL);

  return 0;
}
```

Thanks for any help guys

Comment: You could use any form of [IPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) to implement message passing, that's a good start. You can do this with sockets or named/anonymous pipes etc. Read the link to get started (;

Comment: You could restructure your code and use [fork](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork) a child process and a pipe between to send/receive data. Bare in mind you'd need to keep the parent process in some sort of loop whilst the children are working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For using processes instead of threads you will need to replace `pthread_create()` calls with a method that uses `fork()`.

The parent process then will continue locally with what is now after your `pthread_create()`s.

The child will then call the method being passed in.

The `pid` of the newly created processes will take the role of `tid`.

As you already seem to be using posix semaphores this will continue to work. However, you will need to use named semaphores (see `sem_open`) and use this also in the child processes (before calling your methods) to share the semaphores among your processes.